# Old C++ programmer, Java newbie, needs help about Java multithreading and events

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling, thread-synchronization

I'm "converting" a C++ program (a Borland "Component", to be more precise), which uses a Serial port, to Java. 
That program uses a thread to listen to the serial port, and raises an event when one of the given "event chars" is received (it could be the Carriage Return, ACK, NACK...) or when a userd-defined number of chars are received.

While trying to convert it in Java, I learnt a bit about Threads, make it half-working.
I still have to understand how to raise an event from the listening thread to the main thread... and then i learned the existence of Executors, which seems to be the right way to go, since the user could close, reopen, or change the port multiple times and creating a new thread each time seems to be a bad practice.

So, before struggling for days in the Java concurrency sea, after so much work spent on "raw" Threads, I would ask for an advice, and perhaps a little sample.

What kind of object (i see there's various kind of Executors) should i use to have a serial listener which:

- is able to throw an event to the main thread to pass the received chars array
- can be suspended and restarted (and that can point to a different input stream while suspended... i mean that i could call some of its method while suspended)
- it will be destroyed when not needed (the user could choose to use a socket instead, so the listener will be not needed anymore)

?
I really don't know if some of these points are depending on the object i'll choose, so i've listed them all just to avoid to re-do everything another time 'cause i was not clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some main thread that just must receive the events from other threads (much like a server socket does), some [blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) may be a solution. The main thread could call the `takeLast` in a loop - this will suspend it until any other thread calls `putFirst`, offering a value to take for the same queue.  ([SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) will stall the offering thread till the main thread is ready or alternatively [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) supports a queue of the given size).

With such setup, the main thread cannot also be a GUI thread. Use [invokeAndWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait) if you need to touch interface components like labels or buttons from it.

```
 final BlockingQueue q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(3); 

 new Thread() {
    public void run() {
       while (have_some_messages()) { 
         q.putFirst("Hey!");
       }
    }
 }.start();

 new Thread() {
    public void run() {
       while (also_have_some_messages()) { 
         q.putFirst("Boo!");
       }
    }
 }.start();

 // Main thread will print both Hey and Boo:
 while (must_keep_running()) {
   Object serveIt = q.takeLast();
   System.out.println(serveIt);
 }
```

In case the main thread is a Swing thread (you say JFrame with Swing controls), add a button there to start the servicing thread:

```
Runnable service = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (must_keep_running()) {
    Object serveIt = q.takeLast();
    System.out.println(serveIt);
  }
} finally {
// Re-enable the start button when the service thread exits:
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          bStart.setEnabled(true);
            }
          });
        };
      }
    };

 JButton bStart = new JButton("Start ..");
 bStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         new Thread(service).start();
         bStart.setEnabled(false);
      }    
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the main thread is a JFrame with swing controls.
So, i'd say that i need a somehow synchronized event (or something threadsafe) to pass the chars from the listener to the main thread...
Or am i missing something?

Comment: I have added the explanation how to start the appropriate thread from Swing.

Comment: I opted for an Executor and a listener class derived from a Runnable, with a synchronized event to read the received string.

I don't know if i need to close this question, post my code or what.
thanks, anyway.

Comment: You can accept the best answer by clicking on the V that appears below the answer score. This gives the two more reputation points.

Answer (score -1):

I would make the port-liestening thread based on a [singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html) with perhaps some static ([synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)!) accessors.

A good interface for communicating between threads in your case would be a [Listener/Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) - it should be versatile enough to solve your problem.

Since you are a beginner in Java, one hint: start without threads, just use non-blocking IO. Then - only after everything is working properly - consider using multiple threads. And do it only if you have performance problems.